# unsort a list to get it back the way it was

Tags: python, list, sorting, sortedlist

I want to unsort a list.
For you to understand:

```py
list1 = ["Hi", "Whats up this Morning" "Hello", "Good Morning"]

new_list = sorted(list1, key=len, reverse=True)

["Whats up this Morning", "Good Morning", "Hello", "Hi"]
```

And know it should go back exactly in the same way it was in the beginning

```
["Hi", "Whats up this Morning", "Hello", "Good Morning"]
```

Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: One way is to keep a copy of the unsorted list.

Comment: A list object contains absolutely nothing other than its current sequence of values.  There's no history kept about previous orderings.  You'd need to make a copy of the list before sorting it if you wanted to be able to recover the original order.

Comment: After a list is sorted, there is no way to "unsort" it. You cannot know what the original ordering was. Instead you should just keep a copy of the original list.

Comment: Since you assign the sorted list to another, you already have the unsorted one

Comment: `sorted()` returns a new list.  The original list remains as it was.

Answer (score 1):

Getting to it right out of the gate, `list1` never changes, so as long as you retain this object in memory you will always have a way to refer to the original list, since it's unchanged. `new_list` is a new object, and the absolute simplest thing you can do is keep both these objects and refer to them at will.

Taking your question from a conceptual standpoint: is there a way to keep track of the original order based on the new object? If you absolutely needed to revert to the original order based only on the `new_list`, you could first index the list using `enumerate()`. This tracks the order of your object like so: `(0, 'Hi') (1, 'Whats up this Morning') (2, 'Hello') (3, 'Good Morning')`. Then, you can sort by the length of the second object in each tuple (the original string) with `new_list = sorted(enumerate(list1), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)`. Finally, you can extract your original list (as a tuple) with `words, indices = zip(*new_list)`. Then reversing back to the string is quite simple, see the below example:

```py
list1 = ["Hi", "Whats up this Morning", "Hello", "Good Morning"]
# Pack indices and sort
new_list = sorted(enumerate(list1), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)

# Unpack sorted strings and old indices
indices, words = zip(*new_list)
print(words)  # ('Whats up this Morning', 'Good Morning', 'Hello', 'Hi')
print(indices)  # (1, 3, 2, 0)

# Reverse the sorting based on the old indices
original_list_packed = sorted(zip(indices, words))
print(original_list_packed)  # [(0, 'Hi'), (1, 'Whats up this Morning'), (2, 'Hello'), (3, 'Good Morning')]
_, original_list = zip(*original_list_packed)
print(original_list)  # ('Hi', 'Whats up this Morning', 'Hello', 'Good Morning')
```

Comment: `enumerate` tuples are the opposite order than your example, i.e. `(0, "Hi")` not `("Hi", 0)` just FYI, although, your code handles it correctly

Comment: Good catch, I originally inverted the enumerate and forgot to change the other code when I removed it, editing...

Answer (score 1):

Our list is:

```py
list1 = ["Hi", "Whats up this Morning" "Hello", "Good Morning"]
```

And the new list is:

```py
new_list = sorted(list1, key=len, reverse=True)
```

We sort `list1`and store original keys of `new_list`

```py
list_keys = sorted(range(len(list1)), key=lambda k: list1[k], reverse=True)
```

```py
>>> [1, 0, 2]
```

Ant get back the fist list:

```py
list3 = [None] * len(list1)
for indx in range(len(list_keys)):
    list3[indx] = list1[indx]
```

**Output**

```py
>>> list3
>>> ['Hi', 'Whats up this MorningHello', 'Good Morning']
```